# The type or namespace name 'tool' does not exist in the namespace 'iTextSharp' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: itext

The type or namespace name 'tool' does not exist in the namespace 'iTextSharp' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: I think you are going to have to add more information to this post before anyone if going to be able to help you. At the bottom of your question you will see "edit". Most people on SO respond better if you post some explanation of what you are trying to achieve, what you have tried so far, and what is causing the error. Just posting an error message will not get you an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not available with that package , try to download it separately. I have used the following link [download here](http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_itextsharp/downloads/xmlworker/xmlworker-5.5.4/itextsharp.xmlworker-all-5.5.4.zip/)